# Breakpoint not hit on '__CFXNotificationPost_old'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, gdb

I am trying to set a breakpoint on `__CFXNotificationPost_old` (in gdb) but never seem to stop at it.

I have the following code and am trying to debug it:

```
- (void) notificationHandler:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    DLog(@"|NOTIFICATION| Name [%@] Sender [%@] UserData [%@]",
         notification.name,
         notification.object, 
         notification.userInfo);
}

- (void) startLogging
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationHandler:) name:nil object:nil ];
}
```

Comment: Who told you to set the break-point at `__CFXNotificationPost_old` ???

Comment: http://ftplistchecker.mmsguru.com/blogger/?action=news&id=1284804265

Answer (score 0):

There is no symbol with that name in the 3.2 SDK's CoreFoundation binary. There is one in the 4.1 SDK. You might have more luck breaking on `_CFXNotificationPostNotification`, which is in both SDKs.

It is not clear how this relates to debugging the provided code, particularly as you have not explained what problem you are having with the code.